# Eureka client connection timed out when doing deployment in Apache Tomcat

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cloud, resttemplate, netflix-eureka

I deployed three API on my tomcat server, one as a eureka server other two as a eureka clients.
eureka client x is calling another eureka client y using Resttemplate.
but while running x it is refusing to connect with y.

```
org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on POST request for "http://NOTIFICATION-SERVICE/email/send": Connection refused: connect; nested exception is java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect"
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:784) ~[spring-web-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:710) ~[spring-web-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.postForObject(RestTemplate.java:436) ~[spring-web-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
```

Comment: That error means the rest template didn't replace the service id with a host/port. What is your rest template bean definition

Comment: @ spencergibb  "@Bean
    @LoadBalanced
    public RestTemplate restTemplate() {
        return new RestTemplate();
    }"

Comment: you should add that to the question, rather than as a comment. Can you add your dependencies as well?